# SpriteKit / Objective C - assign one property to two classes

Tags: objective-c, class, properties, sprite-kit

Is it possible to assign one property to multiple classes?

```
NSInteger myValue = _classOne.myproperty & _classTwo.myproperty
```

I want to essentially pass `myValue` to two other classes to trigger some stuff.

Comment: What do you want to do? Your example only makes sense if myproperty is a bitmask that you want to logically AND together to myValue. Of course you can assign the same value to multiple instances of a class, just do it one by one. Example: _classOne.myProperty = myValue; _classTwo.myProperty = myValue;

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I want to grab a number value from myValue, and pass it through to two different classes. Once available in those classes, there are other methods which will use that value. Thanks for your response, the syntax was what I needed. It works for one which means my new class is actually  missing something, which I'll need to work out. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: the question makes no sense. 1. You set properties of instances, you do not pass values to classes. 2. If you want to set properties of two instances of different classes to the same value, just do it: Assign it twice. 3. Then you have to care about data integrity. It seems to be the better approach to let one instance refer the other one and read the value from there.

Comment: The question makes no sense to someone who is more knowledgeable on the subject. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't be asking the question right? Thanks for your response anyway :)